# What is the proper method to make sprites for iOS games in SpriteKit?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I have two questions.

What is the proper method to transfer the physical art I make on paper to a computer so that it utilized as SpriteKit?

What is the proper method to create Sprites on a Mac to be utilized in Xcode7?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming, *and* it is asking for a recommendation.

Comment: @BenPious questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I think this question could be salvaged if it were edited into a question about how to use Xcode to import image files and convert them into SpriteKit sprites.

Comment: @AaronBrager this question needs to be completely redone, 'best of' questions are always off topic, for "software tools commonly used by programmers"  to be ontopic,  it would have to ask specific questions about the software tools,  not recommend which one is best.

Comment: This question belongs on stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally covered in the [Working With Sprites](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html) documentation. Here's a high-level overview though.

You want to create a "textured sprite" which is "the primary way that you bring custom artwork into a scene".

> "This custom artwork might represent characters in your game, background elements, or even user interface elements, but the basic strategy is the same. An artist creates the images, and your game loads them as textures. Then you create sprites with those textures and add them to the scene."

Or in other words, scan your drawings in using any software. Touch them up and make the background transparent (if you want) using image editing software like Photoshop or Pixelmator. Export the result as a PNG file. Drag this file into your Xcode library to import the file into your project.

Then, using the filename, just make an `SKSpriteNode` object. Here's the Objective-C code from the docs:

```
SKSpriteNode *spaceship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rocket.png"];
spaceship.position = CGPointMake(100,100);
[self addChild: spaceship];
```

Here's the same code in Swift:

```
let spaceship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rocket.png")
spaceship.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
addChild(spaceship)
```

I recommend reading that entire document if you have more questions; it's very thorough.